# Can I see the resources from other account in my AWS Organization?

Tags: amazon-web-services

So I have my AWS organization and its me (I'm the owner and admin) and another account.

I can only see the resources which have been activated and how much they are spending.
But my question is, can I actually see what's inside these resources?
For example I have a AmazonEC2 instance, but I can't see any of its properties or configs.

Is there a way to access this information?

Comment: AWS Organizations is a billing model. You still need credentials for each account.

Comment: So basically you're saying there's no way of checking this?

Comment: If you have credentials for each account - yes. If you don't - no.